# Developing Own gui Controls

Tags: user-interface, implementation, gui-toolkit

I'm developing a gui for a game,then,i need to handle everything,from events to draw the controls,its pretty hard.

i have a logical problem,above i will explain what is my question,with a help from a image:

[image]

I want to make this scrollable area,but i dont know how.

I have two functions to draw the Skins(BackGround Area) and the Sprites(items in the image):

```
procedure DrawSprite(LeftOffSet, TopOffSet, Size, ItemId, ItemData1, ItemData2, EdgeR, EdgeG, EdgeB, ClipLeftOffSet, ClipTopOffSet, ClipWidth, clipHeight, TextFont, TextR, TextG, TextB, TextAlign, TextForce: Integer);
procedure DrawSkin(LeftOffSet, TopOffSet, Width, Height, SkinId, ClipLeftOffSet, ClipTopOffSet:integer);
```

WIth Clips parameters,i can control what percentage of skin/sprite i want to draw,but,i dont know how to design it from every control.

I searched a lot on internet,but,i just found about how to do make scrollbars,but not how to deal with scrollable area.

Comment: What language are you using? There are many GUI frameworks out there that could make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Have an overlay image hiding the tops and bottoms of the images when you scroll. Your math just got a whole lot easier.